# String UTF-8 encoding with cyrillic in H2O

Tags: character-encoding, h2o

I load csv file of utf-8 encoding with cyrillic strings. After parsing in Flow interface - i see not cyrillic, but not readable symbols like "пїўпѕЂпѕ™пїђпѕ" How can i use utf-8 cyrillic strings in H2O?

Comment: Would be good to add some code in your question.

Comment: Looks like your file is encoded in UTF-8, but you are using another encoding to decode it, for example, Windows-1251. You have to find out how to make H2O use UTF-8 to decode files, maybe [here](https://community.h2o.ai/questions/1512/importfile-with-character-encoding.html).

Comment: It was csv file with UTF-8 encoding in ubuntu 14.04. In gedit i see cyrillic strings without errors. After parsing in h2o flow i see not readble symbols.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a bug in the Flow interface, but only in the setupParse command. If you continue through and do the import, the data gets imported correctly.

I've reported the bug, with test data and screenshots (taken in Firefox) here:

https://0xdata.atlassian.net/browse/PUBDEV-4640

So if you have additional information, or the bug is behaving differently for you, it'd be good to add it to that bug report.

Answer (score -1):

check your csv file in text and binary presentation to find how Cyrillic text is encoded, if it is UTF-8 it should look like this:

**&#1055;&#1088;&#1080;&#1074;&#1077;&#1090;**

for the word

**Привет**

Comment: If you load a UTF-8 file in any editor or viewer capable of UTF-8 you will just see the text you expect. What you have shown is the way you could encode unicode in an html page if you cannot type the characters.